# Issues With Displaying Queue Contents

Tags: c++, queue, output

First off I will explain the classes and their purposes: ClinicQueue(Queue class, designed to create queues of patients), ClinicNode(typical node class, necessary for Queue), ClinicPatient(stores data about the patients in the queues), and ClinicDriver(used to construct the main application). What I need to do is to display the queue's contents - each node has a data member "info" which is an instance of ClinicPatient and contains a patient's data. In my current code I can only get one patient to print and I know there's is something wrong with my logic, but after 3 hours of the same issue and various attempts at working around it I just can't see what that problem is. How can I fix my code, or write new code to perform the necessary task? Below is the display function as well as the function intended to grab information about patients.

```
ClinicPatient ClinicQueue::getInfo(int pos)  //get information on patients
{
    ClinicNode* Current = front;
    for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++)//for pos +/- 1 only outputs
        //"patient 1: "(a cout in driver)
    {
        Current = Current -> next;
    }
    return Current -> info;   //blows up
}
```

And the display function:

```
void ClinicDriver::Peekaboo() //breaks with more than one patient, skips last patient
{
    bool cont = true;
    int QueueChoice;
    while (cont == true)
    {
        string temp;
        cout << "Select a Doctor by number." << endl;
        cin >> QueueChoice;
        if (status[QueueChoice - 1] == true)
        {
            cout << "Queue is open." << endl;
            string OutputS = "";
            for (int a = 1; a <= Clinic[QueueChoice - 1].getSize(); a++)
            {
                cout << "Patient " << a << " : " << endl; //new, debugging
                OutputS += Clinic[QueueChoice - 1].getInfo(a-1).tostring();//breaks here, works on 1 patient
                OutputS += "\n";
            }
            cout << OutputS << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Queue is empty." << endl;
        }

        cout << "Do you wish to continue?" << endl;
        cin >> temp;
        if (temp == "Yes" || temp == "yes")
        {
            cont = true;
        }
        else
        {
            cont = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the `std::list` or `std::deque` instead of writing your own.

Comment: When you used the debugger, what line is giving you problems?

Comment: I get an access violation so I press break, and the line return Current -> info; is highlighted....this is where it breaks inside the function call in Peekaboo(). The function only works when a queue contains 1 patient. And why the two functions you mentioned?

Comment: the management of both your queue *nodes* (`ClinicNode`) and the limits on the number of nodes present in the queue are important to solving your issues, and you should take the time to ensure they're done *correctly*. The most common problem for beginners with dynamic node chaining is failure to ensure the last `next` is set to NULL. Second to that is failure to ensure NULL is **never** dereferenced. I see *no* attempts at managing *either* in this code. Like most dynamic management problems, throwing more code at the problem will not solve it. Start simple and know how things work *first*.

Comment: I appreciate the advice, I'm just not sure where I would set next to null in getInfo().

Comment: In getInfo(), if I enclose the for loop with while (Current -> next != NULL) it skips over the for loop and just returns the same instance of info each time. I guess I don't understand how to make it see the next patient, although I know it should be set up to work for both size = 1 and size > 1.